# Can I read JavaScript alert box with WatiN?

Tags: watin

I want to use WatiN to verify the error message in a JavaScript alert box. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

see [Trev's Blog](http://tmichealson.blogspot.com/2007/01/handling-alerts-in-watin.html) and [here](http://tmichealson.blogspot.com/2007/03/use-once-dialog.html) as well.

```
using(IE ie = new IE("http://hostname/pagename.htm"))
{
    AlertDialogHandler alertDialogHandler = new AlertDialogHandler();
    using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, alertDialogHandler ))
    {
        /*************************************
        * -- alert -- *
        * *
        * must use the "NoWait" to allow *
        * the code to goto the next line *
        * *
        *************************************/

        alertDialogHandler.WaitUntilExists();
        alertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click();
        ie.WaitForComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies- I didn't read this carefully enough the first time and didn't think it answered my question, but it did! Thanks!